# Cant get "FromQuery" to work with object from Angular

Tags: c#, angular

In my controller I have an action that receive a complex object from Angular call:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult PrescricaoEletronica([FromQuery] Models.Prescricao prescricao)
```

In Angular I call this action this way:

```
this.http.get('api/Relatorios/PrescricaoEletronica', {
  params: {
    prescricao: JSON.stringify(myprescricao)
  }
```

So, using network from chrome I notice that request:

> https://localhost:5001/api/Relatorios/PrescricaoEletronica2?prescricao=%7B%22consultaId%22:84311,%22medicamentoId%22:40698,%22medicamento%22:null,%22qtdEmbalagens%22:1,%22embalagem%22:null,%22embalagemId%22:22,%22observacao%22:%22Tomar%201cp%20a%20noite%22,%22medicamentoNome%22:%22razapina%2015mg%22,%22viaAdministracao%22:null,%22id%22:15277,%22createdAt%22:%222020-05-16T08:21:42.663472%22,%22updatedAt%22:%222020-05-16T20:24:51.288744%22,%22selecionado%22:true%7D

where

> prescricao: {"consultaId":84311,"medicamentoId":40698,"medicamento":null,"qtdEmbalagens":1,"embalagem":null,"embalagemId":22,"observacao":"Tomar 1cp a noite","medicamentoNome":"razapina 15mg","viaAdministracao":null,"id":15277,"createdAt":"2020-05-16T08:21:42.663472","updatedAt":"2020-05-16T20:24:51.288744","selecionado":true}

But all properties from action `prescricao` parameter are null or zero.

This is the c# class:

```
public class Prescricao
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public int? ConsultaId { get; set; }
    public int? MedicamentoId { get; set; }
    public Medicamento Medicamento { get; set; }
    public int QtdEmbalagens { get; set; }
    public Embalagem Embalagem { get; set; }
    public int? EmbalagemId { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string MedicamentoNome
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Medicamento?.Nome;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ViaAdministracao { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Selecionado { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following and let me know...

`this.http.get('api/Relatorios/PrescricaoEletronica', {
  params: myprescricao
}`

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: And what about: this.http.get('api/Relatorios/PrescricaoEletronica', JSON.stringify(myprescricao)

Comment: the error is: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.ts(2769)

Comment: Check the edited version of my answer, I believe you don't need to serialize your param to JSON, the Angular HttpClient will do it for you.

Comment: The easiest way for you to understand that is to check the network tab of chrome on again. In the first case you are "posting" a model that only had one property called `prescricao` and not the expected model with properties `consultaId`, `medicamentoId` and etc...

Comment: I agree - this doesn't compile - not sure why it was marked as the answer.